# How to prevent modal with ajax to reload the page when submitting

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a modal form that show the login modal but whenever i tried to submit even though i dont fill the input its keep reloading page, i already tried copying code that works but its still work in my certain page, If you know the answer please help me know the error. Thank you

Modal :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginClub" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login User SSB/CLUB</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <center><img src="<?= base_url('files/gambar/logoclub/1577137969.png') ?>" width="100px"></center>
        <div class="text-center"><strong>GARUDA ANAK NUSANTARA</strong></div>

        <?php echo form_open('',' id="FormulirLogin" ');?>   

                            <div class="form-group mb-lg no_hp">
                                <label class="control-label">No. HP</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                                    <input name="no_hp" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Masukkan Nomor HP sebagai Username"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-lg password"> 
                                <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-group-icon ">
                                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Masukkan Password"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-lg">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" id="submitform">Login</button>

                        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <hr>
        <div class="text-right">
          <strong>Belum terdaftar?</strong> <br /><a href="daftar">Klik di sini untuk mendaftar...</a><br />
          <strong>Lupa password?</strong> <br /><a href="lupapass">Klik di sini untuk reset password...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button show modal :

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginClub">Login Club</a></li>
```

Ajax :

```
$("#FormulirLogin").submit(function(e) {  
            blurForm();      
            $('.help-block').hide();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $("#submitform").attr("disabled", true);   
            $('#submitform').html('Loading ...');
            var form = $('#FormulirLogin')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST',
                url         : '<?php echo base_url()?>loginclub/authlogin',
                data        : formData, 
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false, 
                dataType    : 'json'
                }).done(function(data) { 
                if ( ! data.success) {       
                    $('input[name=<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>]').val(data.token);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {   
                    $("#submitform").attr("disabled", false);   
                    $('#submitform').html('Login');    
                    var objek = Object.keys(data.errors);  
                    for (var key in data.errors) {
                        if (data.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
                            var msg = '<div class="help-block" for="'+key+'">'+data.errors[key]+'</span>';
                            $('.'+key).addClass('has-error');
                            $('input[name="' + key + '"]').after(msg);  
                        }
                    }   
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                } else { 
                    $('input[name=<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>]').val(data.token);
                    PNotify.removeAll();  
                    $("#submitform").attr("disabled", false);   
                    $('#FormulirLogin')[0].reset();
                    $('#submitform').html('Login');
                    new PNotify({
                        title: 'Notifikasi',
                        text: data.message,
                        type: 'success'
                    }); 
                    window.location='<?php echo base_url()?>'+data.beranda;   
                }
                }).fail(function(data) {  
                    $("#submitform").attr("disabled", false);  
                    $('#submitform').html('Login');    
                    new PNotify({
                        title: 'Notifikasi',
                        text: "Request gagal, browser akan direload",
                        type: 'danger'
                    }); 
                    window.setTimeout(function() {   }, 2000);
                }); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting or removing `window.location='<?php echo base_url()?>'+data.beranda; `?

Comment: I would move the `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the submit function as if for whatever reason something causes an error it won't be executed and the submit will redirect. And then check the JavaScript console for errors

Comment: i already tried to reposition the e.preventDefault(); but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

declare type submit for button login

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" id="submitform">Login</button>
```

and try to move `e.preventDefault()` before `blurForm();`
like

```
$("#FormulirLogin").submit(function(e) {  
e.preventDefault()
blurForm();
```

and make sure the javascript file for those function `blurForm()` and `PNotify()` already loaded.

Comment: my css and js already load all the necessary thing i need but its still reloading, and adding type="button" and reposition my e.preventDefault(); still not working

Comment: what's the error message from your browser console when you click submit button?